# SQL Server foreach loop to read one record at a time from table and then use it to insert or update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which accepts a table as parameter. The parameter is a table containing details of an order basket (users can save their baskets to do the payment at a later time) I want to loop through each item and update if exists and otherwise insert it. something like:

```
foreach select @item_id=item_id,@count=item_count from @details
begin
    if exists(select id from basket_details where item_id=@item_id and basket_id=@id)
         update basket_details set item_id=@item_id,item_count=@count where  item_id=@item_id and basket_id=@id
    else
         insert into basket_details(item_id,item_count) values(@item_id,@count)
end
```

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: You can use `MERGE` statement - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: SQL Server doesn't do looping very well - it's a **set-based** architecture, really. Think about your input table as a **set of rows** that you need to merge into your existing database. Looping is procedural - fine in VB, frowned upon in T-SQL

Comment: after many years of using sql server, its funny, exciting and a bit disapointing to say that I didn't know about merge. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to do this. I guess your are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [BasketID] INT
    ,[ProductID] INT
    ,[Count] TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([BasketID], [ProductID], [Count])
VALUES (1, 1, 100)
      ,(1, 2, 50)
      ,(2, 3, 10)
      ,(2, 5, 15)
      ,(2, 6, 20)

DECLARE @RecordsToInsertOrUpdate TABLE
(
     [BasketID] INT
    ,[ProductID] INT
    ,[Count] TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @RecordsToInsertOrUpdate ([BasketID], [ProductID], [Count])
VALUES (1, 1, 99) -- Update
      ,(1, 2, 99) -- Update
      ,(1, 7, 10) -- Insert
      ,(2, 7, 10) -- Insert

MERGE @DataSource AS [Target]
USING
(
    SELECT [BasketID]
          ,[ProductID]
          ,[Count]
    FROM @RecordsToInsertOrUpdate 
) AS [Source]
ON [Target].[BasketID] = [Source].[BasketID]
  AND [Target].[ProductID] = [Source].[ProductID]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [Count] = [Source].[Count]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([BasketID], [ProductID], [Count])
    VALUES ([Source].[BasketID], [Source].[ProductID], [Source].[Count]);

SELECT [BasketID] 
      ,[ProductID] 
      ,[Count] 
FROM @DataSource
```

The statement above will update the records count in `@DataSource` table if there is a match in the `@RecordsToInsertOrUpdate` table, otherwise it will insert the new record form the `@RecordsToInsertOrUpdate` table.

Answer (score 2):

Your merge statement would look something like this:

```
MERGE basket_details b
USING @details d
    ON d.item_id = b.item_id
    AND d.basket_id = d.basket_id
WHEN MATCHED AND b.item_count != d.item_count THEN
    UPDATE SET  Item_count = d.item_count
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (basket_id, item_id, item_count)
    VALUES (d.basket_id, d.item_id, d.item_count)
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
```